# OleDbDataAdapter exception with ntext using SQL Server CE 3.5

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledb

> OleDbDataAdapter internal error: invalid row set accessor: Ordinal=6 Status=UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION

All I'm doing is trying to do a simple select statement. The field in ordinal 6 is a `NTEXT` field.  Are they telling me I can't use `NTEXT` fields in my database with OleDb providers? Is there any workaround here?

Comment: You're using both c# and sql server compact - why not use the sqlce namespace/provider?

Comment: We are actually trying to support multiple database types, being SQL Server 2005, SQL Server CE, and Microsoft Access.  The underlying datalayer would require a massive rewrite to be able to use the SqlCeConnection object.  We have many reader.HasRows calls within the data layer which doesn't work under SqlCe namespace but does under the OleDb one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your supposition is correct. NTEXT is no longer supported in string functions for the latest .NET tools. I'd suggest, since you're using SQL 2005, to change the column type in the database to NVARCHAR.